# Over-current/short-circuit protection for the battery bank

Tags: current, current-limiting, fuses, high-current, over-current

I am using a 24 V 100 A additional vehicle alternator for charging my additional battery bank of 24 V. I need an over-current/short-circuit protection for my battery bank. I am considering using a DC fuse between batteries and alternator. Can you please suggest an effective type and also rating of DC fuse which is suitable for my requirement?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent excss charging current or backflow into the alternator. The 1st is handled by a regulator and / or a charge controller . If the alternator is capable of vast overcharge a maybe 50% over max desired current slow blow fuse will probably suffice. || Backflow from battery only happens if the alternator rectifiers fail. A fuse rated at max acceptabvle current should be OK. If both of the above are required then the larger of the two is needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are bolt down fuses specifically designed for this kind of application.  They are slow blow (to allow spike loads such as starting), but protect against short circuits and long term overload.

Several manufacturers offer products, but the Littlefuse [MEGA+](https://www.littelfuse.com/products/fuses/automotive-passenger-car/high-current-fuses/mega-plus-32v) range are a good starting point, going from 40A to 650A.